# display a thumbnail, make that a link to an imageblob on a mysql server

Tags: php, html, mysql, image, hyperlink

I'm trying to create a link to the full size image, from a image displayed on an html page.

The image displays properly, but I can't for the life of me - figure out how to make it so that when I click on that image - a new page (or anything else really) with the full image will show up-- currently I am getting no results.

```php
('there is a long echo before this part but simply this is what i have')
echo '<td> <a scr="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode($row['PicFront']).'" > 
                    <img  src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode($row['PicFront']).'">
                    </a>';
```

Comment: <a src= "You have a typo here it should be src not scr" After open the inspector and make sure you have the right link from php

Comment: an anchor tag ( `a` ) does not have a `src` attribute nor the incorrect `scr` attribute but instead has the `href` attribute

Comment: the href tag is recognized. but now I think the problem is the address - how do you specify the cell in a database - and link to an image blob?